# some confusion about ReplaceRepeated

Tags: replacement, broken-code

This is Right.

```
NestWhile[Log, 100, # > 1 &]
{100} //. {x_} /; x > 1 :> {Log[x]}
100. //. x_ /; x > 1 :> Log[x]
```

This is wrong,why?

```
100 //. x_ /; x > 1 :> Log[x]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your final form fails is that `ReplaceRepeated` will replace deeper parts of the expression when the first pattern test fails.  Like this:

```
Log[Log[Log[100]]] /. x_ /; x > 1 :> flag[x]
```

> ```
> Log[flag[Log[Log[100]]]]
> ```

You'll get a similar (though not identical) error message from this:

```
Nest[Log, 100, 50] > 1;
```

> Greater::nord: Invalid comparison with Log[Log[Log[Log[Log[Log[Log[Log[<<1>>]]]]]]]] attempted. >>

After `Log` is nested five times you get the `I Pi` term seen in your original message:

```
 Nest[Log, 100, 5]
```

> ```
> I π + Log[-Log[Log[Log[Log[100]]]]]
> ```

Comment: Right, and `Log[100.]` evaluates so it has no deeper pieces.